# Spaces between elements of lists in dart

Tags: dart

```
products = ["Coke",23,34];
```

I want to print this list into proper output view, means the spaces should remain same in any compiler.

```
ItemName    Price     Cost 
Coke        23        34
```

Comment: Just a general advice, you should not use a `List` to contain different types of information like you are doing here. Instead, you should create a class so you can have a list of objects of this class. This will make your code type safe and easier to understand.

Comment: Also, can you describe if there are any rules about how the spacing should work? I don't seem to find any system in your current example so I might just assume it does not matter as long as things looks similar to the example.

Comment: You could use [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) widget, it is more reliable, moreover I don't agree about creating classes/objects when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  printProducts(
    header: const ['ItemName', 'Price', 'Cost'],
    products: [
      ["Coke", 23, 34]
    ],
    columnSpace: 12,
  );
  // ItemName    Price       Cost
  // Coke        23          34
}

/// Method that prints a list of products to standout output in a table form.
/// The method takes the following three arguments:
///
/// * [header] defines the first row of the table and should be a list of names
/// for each column.
///
/// * [products] List of products (where each product is defined as a
/// List<Object> where each element is column value.
///
/// * [columnSpace] defines the space reserved for each column. This value
/// should be set to a value larger that the widest item (including header)
void printProducts({
  required List<String> header,
  required List<List<Object>> products,
  required int columnSpace,
}) {
  // StringBuffer is used so we can add more data to a line of String as we go
  // through each column of data. This is needed since the "print" function will
  // automatically add a newline after printing to the screen.
  final stringBuffer = StringBuffer();

  // Start with the header and then iterate over each product. The
  // [header, ...products] syntax means that we defines a new list containing
  // first "header" and then all elements (... means we add all elements from
  // another iterable compatible object (e.g. list)) of "products". We are then
  // iterating over this new list.
  for (final row in [header, ...products]) {
    // Go though each column in our row. We use a normal for-loop since we want
    // to be able to check if we are at the last element.
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      // Write our column to the StringBuffer. We checks if we are at the last
      // element since if that is the case, we don't need to add the padding to
      // the right.
      //
      // The `padRight` will check the size of the String and add padding
      // (by default, it uses spaces) to make sure the String is a given length.
      stringBuffer.write(
        i == header.length - 1
            ? row[i]
            : row[i].toString().padRight(columnSpace),
      );
    }

    // Print the content of our StringBuffer (contains one line of data).
    print(stringBuffer);

    // Clear the StringBuffer so it does not contain any data. We can then reuse
    // it for the next line of data.
    stringBuffer.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: @akhanhanif Does the code what you want? I don't want to add a detailed explanation if I am afterwards going to change the solution because of some problems.

Comment: @akhanhanif Updated my answer with some explanation about what the code does. Please tell me if there are still some parts of the code you need help with to understand.